# Partition/Data inaccessible after using GParted Live to Extend Partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, data-recovery, gparted, file-corruption

I had some unallocated Free Space of 260MB on my 1TB HDD. I used Gparted Live OS to extend my HDD's Size. Gparted moved all the data to left side of the HDD and had extended the partition size. Took a whole Night for the process to complete.

When I first booted into Windows every partition looked as same size with the files. But when I opened a folder, I was left with this error

[image: Error's Screenshot]

Any folder I open on any partition of the HDD gives me the same message. FYI, I have Windows Installed on a Separate SSD.

Is there any way to make my files & folders back to an accessible state?

(Please don't suggest some Data Recovery Software. Suggest me some ways to get my data back )

I noticed that all my 3 partitions had been merged into one NTFS Partition...

[image: AOMEI Partition Assistant Screenshot]

MY HDD was a Dynamic Drive. But now after extending my partion using Gparted My HDD Shows itself as a Basic Drive.

Using `chkdsk` doesn't help. It states that my drive is RAW.

Comment: Well, lesson learned - you should never do such dangerous operations without creating backups first. Did you try something as simple as `chkdsk /f` on that partition?

Comment: chkdsk doesn't work... Displays Just this error... The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.

Comment: There were and still are 0 mentions of `RAW` partition in your question. Instead of spamming triple dots edit it to be accurate.

Comment: Just Edited my question with  a few more details.

Comment: There's no mentions stating that this is a RAW disk anywhere on Disk Management or some other Place just the CMD states that this is a RAW Drive.

Comment: Please include the chkdsk info in the question too. That suggests a more serious corruption. Recovery software might be something you'll have to use, it's a much better bet than triyng to play around with the disk/paritions even further regardless, especially if you have files that are important to recover.

Comment: "(Please don't suggest some Data Recovery Software. Suggest me some ways to get my data back)" - Data recovery software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: Will Try Those ASAP as I don't have my PC with me Right now. Anyway Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue myself.

Use **AOMEI Partition Assistant** to **Delete the Volume (Without wiping the data)** From the Storage device in which the partitions are inaccessible.

Use the **Partition Recovery Tool** From AOMEI Partition Recovery and run **Full Scan**. (Might take a few hours depending on the size and speed of your Storage Device).

Now the Partitions will be listed. Select the Partitions you wish to Recover and Select **Recover**.

All your inaccessible/lost partitions will be available back as before.